# How can I interpolate between 2 points when drawing with canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, interpolation

I have a paint-style application that works with touch events.

[image: example]

The JavaScript code is...

```
var RADIUS = 10;
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

var getRandomColorFragment = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
};

document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + [getRandomColorFragment(), getRandomColorFragment(), getRandomColorFragment()].join() + ")";
});

document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function (event) {
    // Prevent default behavior of scrolling elements.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get a reference to the first touch placed.
    var touch = event.touches[0];

    // Draw a circle at the location of the finger.
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(touch.pageX - RADIUS, touch.pageY - RADIUS, RADIUS, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrWep/).

You can test this on a platform that doesn't support touch events by using Chrome and opening the Web Inspector's settings and choosing [*Emulate touch events*](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#emulate-touch-events).

When the finger/pointer moves very fast, it fails to paint the canvas continually like which would be expected (see screenshot above). It seems I can only get the touches' coordinates only as fast as the `touchmove` event is triggered.

I thought that I could determine if there is a big enough gap between arcs using the Distance Formula (`c2 = a2 + b2`) and determining if it's larger than the `RADIUS` constant. This part worked well. The next thing I needed to figure out is how to interpolate between the two points: the previous registered touch's coordinates and the newly registered coordinates'.

So, essentially, I'd like to know how I could interpolate between the two points I have to determine how to *fill-in* the gap.

Comment: How about iterating between those two points (using Bresenham's line algorithm) and drawing circle in every single point you visit ?

Comment: Bresenham's algorithm does not allow to draw "thick" lines with rounded corners. But there already is implemented "lineTo" method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to draw a line from last mouse position to the new mouse postition. But you are drawing a circle at the new position instead. Why?

Why don't you do it this way?

```
onTouchStart: ctx.moveTo(x,y);

onTouchMove: ctx.lineTo(x,y);
```

All interpolation, antialiasing etc. is already included in "lineTo" function. Use  `ctx.lineCap = "round";` to have round corners.

If you still want to interpolate numbers, here is the function:

```
function interpolate(a, b, frac) // points A and B, frac between 0 and 1
{
    var nx = a.x+(b.x-a.x)*frac;
    var ny = a.y+(b.y-a.y)*frac;
    return {x:nx,  y:ny};
}

interpolate({x:2, y:2}, {x:4,y:4}, 0.5); // returns {x:3, y:3}
```