# Get coordinates of half of the length of the bezier curve

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bezier

I have an ellipse which is drawn with 4 beziercurves.

I want to draw a point on every beziercurve.

The point should be in the middle of the length of the beziercurve (half of the length of the bezier curve).

How do I get the coordinates of this points?

Ist there a formula or a algorithm which can do that?

[image: picture which hopefully will describe my question]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227300/how-to-draw-bezier-curves-with-native-javascript-code-without-ctx-beziercurveto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw Bezier curves with native Javascript code without ctx.bezierCurveTo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227300/how-to-draw-bezier-curves-with-native-javascript-code-without-ctx-beziercurveto)

Comment: My problem is not to draw the beziercurve but to find out the coordinates of the center of the beziercurve

Comment: Can you provide the method which you are drawing the bezier with? If you are using ctx, please, provide the actual coordinates.

Comment: This is a maths question.  The fact that you want to use it in an application is irrelevant.  Just google the question itself and then come back if you need help doing it in Javascript (once you know how to actually do it).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the art of finding such formulas has a home on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Archer Thank you for your answer. I have searched google and forums for the last 3 houres and still haven't found a solution.

Comment: @coder041, I edited my answer. I hope you can use it now (in spite of it got a downvote it is fully working with example). Please, let me know if you have any question regarding.

Comment: you're showing an ellipse, which is literally impossible to draw with Bezier curves, so to draw any kind of ellipse (including circles) you need multiple Beziers. If you can show how many Beziers you're using, and what order they are, then this question has an answer. Otherwise, there's not enough information. If you really do mean "on the ellipse", then Beziers are irrelevant and you want the maths for finding a point on an ellipse at some distance or angle.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The ellipse is drawn with 4 bezier curves. I want the coordinates of the middlepoint on the bezier curve in the right bottom corner.

Comment: Then please update your illustration to show just one curve rather than four, and phrase your question in terms of that one curve, and probably explain what you mean with "the middle point" (i.e. expressed in term of some angle, or some distance ratio, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

My solution is also not a real ellipsis, as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans highlighted, but an ellipsis-like bezier curve. If **half** means the 3:1 division point of the *length* of the bottom curve (and not 45 degree from the axis) the solution looks like this with ctx and using @ivan-kuckir's [interpolation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190981/how-can-i-interpolate-between-2-points-when-drawing-with-canvas):

```js
function interpolate(a, b, frac){
  var nx = a.x+(b.x-a.x)*frac;
  var ny = a.y+(b.y-a.y)*frac;
  return {x:nx,  y:ny};
}

function getDivisionPointOfBezier(cp1, cp2, cp3, cp4, frac) {
  var p1 = interpolate(cp1, cp2, frac);
  var p2 = interpolate(cp2, cp3, frac);
  var p3 = interpolate(cp3, cp4, frac);

  var p4 = interpolate(p1, p2, frac);
  var p5 = interpolate(p2, p3, frac);

  var p6 = interpolate(p4, p5, frac);
  return p6;
}

// control points of the ellipsis bezier
var cp1 = {x:0, y:50};
var cp2 = {x:0, y:100};
var cp3 = {x:200, y:100};
var cp4 = {x:200, y:50};
var cp5 = {x:200, y:0};
var cp6 = {x:0, y:0};


var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


ctx.beginPath();

// bottom half-curve
ctx.moveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp2.x, cp2.y, cp3.x, cp3.y, cp4.x, cp4.y);

// top half-curve
ctx.moveTo(cp4.x, cp4.y);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp5.x, cp5.y, cp6.x, cp6.y, cp1.x, cp1.y);

ctx.stroke();

// draw red point
var divPoint = getDivisionPointOfBezier(cp1, cp2, cp3, cp4, 0.75);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.arc(divPoint.x,divPoint.y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
```

This drawing represents the calculation on the bottom part. This how the [bézier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) is calculating the position of each point (black dots represent the control points), and we are looking for the 3:1 division point.
[image]